# Kivy: accessing a method on a different class

Tags: python, binding, popup, parent, kivy

Let's pretend I am building a tic-tac-toe game (becouse it's pretty similar as a structure)
I want the result to be shown in a popup, with a new game button, and I want this popup to let me access settings (with another button) and change them, always staying within the popup, then leave and finally close it and start a new game.

I wish i could keep things ordered and therefore have a separate popup class where i can build my custom popup.

I have the newgame method and reset method as method of my game-grid class, as obvious. 
Methods for changing settings are, on the other hand, on a custom settings class

While designing the popup class how can I bind it's buttons (e.g new game) to methods that are contained on a completly different class? I've looked on some kv examples and they usually use root.blabla.method to acces a method that is in a different position of the same tree (in the .kv file) but here the methods I am trying to reach are out of the tree!

I'll try to put some example code to make it more clear

```
class Settings():

    def changeSettings(self):
        ....

class GmeGrid(GridLayout):

    def newGame(self):
        ....

    def reset(self):
        ...

class customPopup(Popup):

    pass
```

Then, on a .kv file I wish I could bind some popup's buttons to the newGame and change settings methods

The problem here is that I should bind buttons on the popop class to the mothods of completly different class and I don't know how to to that (on the .kv file especially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the widget has been fully instantiated and added to the widget tree, you can use `self.parent` to access the widget's parent. You might look into passing references instead though:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<CustomPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        # some settings stuff here
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: 'New Game'
                on_press: root.do_new_game()
''')

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    settings_widget = ObjectProperty()
    new_game = ObjectProperty()

    def do_new_game(self):
        self.settings_widget.some_property = some_value
        self.dismiss()
        self.new_game()

p = CustomPopup(settings_widget=my_widget, new_game=mygame.newGame)
p.open()
```

This is better that assuming the parent has the settings, because if you change where you keep the settings, you just need to change one reference.

Comment: Well that isn't what I really ment. This way I could acces the settings class method inside the popup (as the settings class is a member of it) but not any method which isn't "under" the popup class (as for eg a new game method) self.parent allows me to climb the tree one level but for more than one level? I may edit the question to get the point more clear. Thank you anyway

Comment: @AscanioFX I added an example for referencing a method.

Comment: @RyanP Thank you! Mmm I find your solution really interesting! That way I would pass my settings widget and any function i might need to the CustomPopup class when initializing it. I haven't fully understood what kivy properties are but that's not the topic of this question. If I pass my_widget to the CustomPopup would it create a copy of it (without changing the original setting widget when beeing modified) or modified it as "by reference" (I come from a C background)

Comment: Everything in Python is passed by object reference. Think of these as magical pointers which automatically reference/dereference themselves. So if you pass `my_widget` to `CustomPopup` it will be a separate pointer containing the same value (the same reference).

Comment: This is a nice little article describing the differences between pass by value, pass by reference, and pass by object-reference. http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/