# Update widget inside function

Tags: android, python, kivy

My problem is, that I'm trying to **update** **a widgets** ***background color*** **inside a function**, and swap it back after some time. The problem is, that Kivy seems to update the widgets as soon as every function is done, and it can go back into it's own mystery loop. Is there a function to update the whole widget, or the app on command? I'm not using a .kv-file for my widgets.

Comment: You can give an id to that widget in the **kv** file or use **bind method**. See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202801/how-to-access-id-widget-of-different-class-from-a-kivy-file-kv/30220800#30220800

Comment: Got it myself. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it myself.
At the point, where the update should take place I splittet my function. To show you what I mean:

**Before**

```
function():
    widget.text = "new text"
    #update?!
    widget.text = "old text again"
```

**After**

```
function():
    widget.text = "new text"
    Clock.schedule_once(functionend)

functionend():
    widget.text = "old text again"
```

In case you don't understand my process, feel free to ask, and I'll explain.